# Handout option in Beamer incompatible with \itemize?

Tags: beamer, itemize, handout

I am making a Beamer presentation and want to use the handout option. However, it turns out that when I add `[handout]` to the document class, the `itemize`-environment does not work properly and all items are displayed at once, although I specify that they should be revealed pointwise. What is wrong?

Here is my preamble and an example:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{phonetic}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
 \let\eachwordone\itshape
\addbibresource{ref2.bib}


\beamertemplateballitem


\title{XXX}
\subtitle{YYY}
\author{XXX}
\institute{Flafla}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\textunderscript}[1]{$_{\text{#1}}$}

\begin{document}



\frame{


\begin{itemize}

\item<2-> Blabla 

\item<3-> Flafla

\item<4-> Dada

\end{itemize}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beamer user guide is very clear about that (mode specifications, 9.6.2):

> For this reason, if you write `\only<3>{Text}` and you are in handout
>   mode, the text will be shown on all slides since there is no
>   restriction specified for handouts and since the `3` is the same as
>   `beamer:3`.

You have to specify the restrictions for the presentation and for the handout. But be aware, that you usually design a presentation without `handout`. That option is just used to print the handouts and then removed if you give your presentation.

Here's a real MWE "fixing" your problem (workaround around beamer's design):

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\beamertemplateballitem

\title{XXX}
\subtitle{YYY}
\author{XXX}
\institute{Flafla}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\begin{itemize}
\item<2- | handout:2-> Blabla 
\item<3- | handout:3-> Flafla
\item<4- | handout:4-> Dada
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```